# How to start a docker container by jenkins?

Tags: docker, jenkins, version-control, dockerfile, containers

I am trying to start a container using Jenkins and a Dockerfile in my SCM.
Jenkins uses the Dockerfile from my SCM repository and builds the image on a remote server having a Dockerfile. This is done using the "cloud bees docker build and publish plugin".

When I ssh to the server, I see that the image has been built with the tags I had defined in Jenkins.

```
# docker image ls
```

What I am not able to do is run a container for the image that has been built. How to get the image-id and start the container? Shouldn't it have been very simple given many plugins are provided?

Comment: Have you read [Using Docker with Pipeline](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/docker/) in the Jenkins documentation?  You can go off-road with `sh "docker ..."`, but the provided pipeline constructs should cover most of the common cases.

Answer (score 0):

Could your problem be related to how to refer to the recently created docker in order tu run it? Can you provide an extract of your pipeline and how you are trying to achieve this?

It that was the case, there are different solutions, one being specifying a tag during the Docker creation, so you can then refer to it to run it.

In reply to how to work with image-ids, the docker build process will return the image id of the docker it creates. You can capture that id, and then use to run the docker.

Comment: I have tried to use the plugin as shown in the link. The only thing is I cannot see any option of starting the container. Am I doing something wrong? https://github.com/jenkinsci/docker-build-publish-plugin#usage

Comment: Can you post the code/step related to running the newly created docker? If you have tagged it during its creation a simple Shell step with `docker run <docker_tag>` should start your docker assuming it exists on the local machine (which you say it does)

Comment: The step is exectly the same  as the link provided by me two comments ago. Also, what you say works. But I am confused that why does it need a separate build step to run the command manually, shouldn't they should have been just checkbox in the  gui here- github.com/jenkinsci/docker-build-publish-plugin#usage  ? When jenkins docker plugin has already provided so many options, why skip the most important one?

Comment: I can only guess as of why the plugin developers would include or not that checkbox in their development.  
Since the plugin is called `Build and Publish` that seems to be what they have focused on.  
If you where using a scripted pipeline, instead of one configured using the GUI, your use case would be covered. Now, GUI based config is at times more limited.  

You can try to find a different plugin that provides the option needed. Now, if the additional bash steps works, why not use it?

Answer (score 0):

start the container yourself on the VM by using standard docker run command.

use a software like [watchtower](https://github.com/containrrr/watchtower) to restart the container with an updated version when available